# Oracle SQL UNION ALL where T1.ID <> T2.ID

Tags: sql, oracle, union, union-all

I have two tables `Test_Table` and `Test_Table2`. I want the `UNION ALL` or `UNION` of the two but I only want the rows from `TEST_TABLE2` that I do not have an ID for in `TEST_TABLE`. IDs could be unique to either table or exist in both tables as they are populated from two different systems.

I have been running this statement and then just handling the duplicate IDs down the road but I would like there not to be duplicate IDs.

```
SELECT ID, DATE_VALUE, TEXT_VALUE, TABLESOURCE FROM TEST_TABLE
UNION
SELECT ID, OTHER_DATE_VALUE AS DATE_VALUE, OTHER_TEXT_VALUE AS TEXT_VALUE, TABLESOURCE FROM TEST_TABLE2;
```

Here are the tables.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2db484/2

I am using ***"Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.3.0 - 64bit Production"***

I have not been able to get the SQL to do this. How can I get these rows.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can left join Test_Table to TestTable2 to find the rows that don't match:

```
SELECT 
  ID, DATE_VALUE, TEXT_VALUE, TABLESOURCE 
FROM TEST_TABLE
UNION -- or UNION ALL, which might be faster
SELECT 
  t2.ID, t2.OTHER_DATE_VALUE AS DATE_VALUE, t2.OTHER_TEXT_VALUE AS TEXT_VALUE, t2.TABLESOURCE 
FROM 
  TEST_TABLE2 t2
  LEFT JOIN TEST_TABLE t on t.ID = t2.ID
WHERE
  t.ID IS NULL
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2db484/6

Alternatively, you can use `WHERE NOT EXISTS ...` to return only the rows for `t2` that don't have  matching row in `t`:

```
SELECT 
  ID, DATE_VALUE, TEXT_VALUE, TABLESOURCE 
FROM TEST_TABLE
UNION -- or UNION ALL, which might be faster
SELECT 
  ID, 
  OTHER_DATE_VALUE, -- Note, you don't need the alias in the second query of the union.
  OTHER_TEXT_VALUE AS TEXT_VALUE, -- Although you can leave it as 'self-documentation'.
  TABLESOURCE 
FROM 
  TEST_TABLE2 t2
WHERE
  NOT EXISTS 
    (SELECT 'x' FROM TEST_TABLE t WHERE t.ID = t2.ID)
```

Also, have a look at `MINUS` and `INTERSECT`, which can be used just like `UNION`, but to create a dataset without matching record in another, or a dataset of on those records that match the other dataset. See: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/queries004.htm

I don't think either `MINUS` or `INTERSECT` would make this specific case easier, but they may be useful if you have a similar issue.

Comment: Thank you, I tried the Where Not Exists and that gave me exactly what I need.

Answer (score 2):

I would write this as:

```
SELECT ID, DATE_VALUE, TEXT_VALUE, TABLESOURCE
FROM TEST_TABLE
UNION ALL
SELECT ID, OTHER_DATE_VALUE AS DATE_VALUE, OTHER_TEXT_VALUE AS TEXT_VALUE, TABLESOURCE
FROM TEST_TABLE2 T2
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM TEST_TABLE T WHERE T.ID = T2.ID);
```

Because you are selecting distinct `id`s, you do not need `union`.  `union all` is more efficient because it does not add the step of removing duplicates.

Comment: Thanks, I did change my statement to be Union All since the Union wasnt handling the dups I cared about. The Union All runs much faster.